# Graph traits of a subgraph

Tags: c++, boost, subgraph

I have a graph and I want to change its type to subgraph to be able to divide it into more subgraphs to get a more ordinate print with graphviz.
The problem is that when I add the subgraph propriety to my graph the vertex descriptor is no longer working.

Code before modification:

```
    #include "Node.cpp"
    #include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
    #include <boost/property_map/property_map.hpp>
    #include <boost/graph/graph_traits.hpp>
    #include <boost/graph/subgraph.hpp>

    using namespace boost;

    typedef adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, directedS, Node, property < edge_weight_t, float > > mygraph;
    typedef graph_traits < mygraph >::vertex_descriptor vertex_descriptor;
    ...
```

Code after changing the graph to subgraph:

```
    #include "Node.cpp"
    #include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
    #include <boost/property_map/property_map.hpp>
    #include <boost/graph/graph_traits.hpp>
    #include <boost/graph/subgraph.hpp>

    using namespace boost;

   typedef subgraph<adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, directedS, Node, property < edge_weight_t, float > > >mygraph;
   typedef graph_traits < mygraph >::vertex_descriptor vertex_descriptor;   //ERROR
   ...
```

What is the problem? And how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problems isn't with the traits per se.

The subgraph **requires** an edge_index property, because it stores a local mapping:

```
    typedef std::map<edge_index_type, edge_descriptor> LocalEdgeMap;
    LocalEdgeMap m_local_edge; // global -> local
```

Because there's no `edge_index_t` property, the map's key type evaluates to `void`.

This is documented here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0b1/libs/graph/doc/subgraph.html

> *The underlying graph type is required to have vertex_index and edge_index internal properties, so we add an edge index property to the adjacency list. We do not need to add a vertex index properety because that is built in to the adjacency_list. We will be building the graph and subgraphs in Figure 1, so we will need a total of six vertices*

Consider adding an edge index:

```
typedef subgraph<adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, directedS, Node, property < edge_index_t, index > > >mygraph;
typedef graph_traits < mygraph >::vertex_descriptor vertex_descriptor;   // COMPILES
```

Comment: It compiles but the edge_weight property is used later on in my code so I can't just replace it with edge_index, is there a way around?

Comment: @W4lker I'm pretty sure you can combine the edge properties. After all that's the entire reason that properties are _tagged_ (`edge_index_t` and `edge_weight_t` being the _tags_). I'd read the documentation for you if I had the time :)

Comment: Yes! Brilliant! I forgot of the custom label setting! Thank you!